# TextView for Static TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, viewcontroller

I have a TableViewController with static cells. For one cell, I placed a TextView (editable) on Storyboard and connected the TableViewCell as an outlet to the TableViewController. I also created a class for the TableViewCell and connected outlet for TextView.

Even though everything seems okay, the keyboard doesn't open. I think it's because of the delegates.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableViewCell: MyCell!

} 

  viewDidLoad() {

       myTableViewCell.myTextView.delegate = self

  }
```

---

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

}
```

I also placed an extension:

```
extension TableViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
  }
}
```

I'm trying on iPhone, not Simulator :/

I generated a sample project that creates the issue. [Please check here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxWHl6OLoWW6RXh0MlJ0cldKZjQ)

Comment: It doesn't depend on delegate assignment. You set or not delegate it should open. Are you testing on simulator or real device?

Comment: You probably forgot to set the cell class in interface builder?

Comment: so you are getting the texview but a keyboard is not open? if you are checking in simulator please check for the hardware keyboard option

Comment: Yes, I also tested on iPhone. The keyboard doesn't open. I can see dummy text on the view. I have set MyCell on Storyboard

Comment: Chack if `UITextViewDelegate` methods get called after click on textView or not. Maybe your `AboutTableViewCell.myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE`

Comment: @Shamsiddin `userInteractionEnabled` is ticked on Storyboard :/ Doesn't it guarantee it?

Comment: Anyways check methods of `UITextViewDelegate`, for example `textViewDidBeginEditing:` method. Maybe you are using `GestureRecognizer` incorrectly or your `textView.superView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE`

Comment: I generated a sample project that creates the issue. [Please check here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxWHl6OLoWW6RXh0MlJ0cldKZjQ). I'd be grateful anyone could check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is shown with red rectangle, you shoulld check `Selectable` property of your `textView`. [image]

Comment: I tested it on iPhone, it's definitely not that

Comment: I think you should delete this answer.. It's definitely not the case